# PHP Generated code looks fine, but throws error in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, syntax-error

I have the following code which generates a dynamic section of a validation script:

```
<script>
        $().ready(function() {

            $("#newtranslation").validate({
                    slanguage: "required",
                    tlangs: "required",
                    street: "required",
                    city: "required",
                    state: "required",
                    zip: "required",
                    docname: "required",
                    <?
                    $select_attachments = " SELECT  `doc_id`
                                            FROM    `li_appointments`.`li_trans_source_doc`
                                            Where   `trans_id` = $translation_id;";

                    $result = mysql_query($select_attachments);
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    $more_items = $more_items . $row['doc_id'] . 'pages: "required", ' . PHP_EOL;
                    $more_items = $more_items . $row['doc_id'] . 'words: "required", ' . PHP_EOL;
                    }
                    echo substr($more_items, 0, -2);
                    ?>
                },
                messages: {

                    slanguage: {
                        required: "Please enter a source language"
                    },
                    tlanguage: {
                        required: "Please enter a target language"
                    },
                    docname: {
                        required: "Please upload a document before submitting"
                    }
                },
                errorElement: "div",
                wrapper: "div",  // a wrapper around the error message
                 errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                element.before(error);
                offset = element.offset();
                error.css('top', offset.top - element.outerHeight());
                }
            });
        });
```

That outputs the following:

```
$().ready(function() {

            $("#newtranslation").validate({
                    slanguage: "required",
                    tlangs: "required",
                    street: "required",
                    city: "required",
                    state: "required",
                    zip: "required",
                    docname: "required",
                    106pages: "required", 
 106words: "required", 
 107pages: "required", 
 107words: "required",                  },
                messages: {

                    slanguage: {
                        required: "Please enter a source language"
                    },
                    tlanguage: {
                        required: "Please enter a target language"
                    },
                    docname: {
                        required: "Please upload a document before submitting"
                    }
                },
                errorElement: "div",
                wrapper: "div",  // a wrapper around the error message
                 errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                element.before(error);
                offset = element.offset();
                error.css('top', offset.top - element.outerHeight());
                }
            });
        });
```

However I get the following error.  I can't see anything wrong, so why is this not working?

```
  8                          state: "required",
  9                          zip: "required",
  10                          docname: "required",
  11                          106pages: "required", 
      =========^
      SyntaxError: missing : after property id
  12  106words: "required", 
  13  107pages: "required",
```

14  107words: "required",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't start a property/variable name with a digit: `106pages`. It must start with a letter, underscore, or $.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals):

> A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9). Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters "A" through "Z" (uppercase) and the characters "a" through "z" (lowercase).
>
> Starting with JavaScript 1.5, you can use ISO 8859-1 or Unicode letters such as å and ü in identifiers. You can also use the \uXXXX Unicode escape sequences as characters in identifiers.

Comment: Thank you.  This took care of it.  Somehow I had never run into this before.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `106pages: "required"` should be `"106pages": "required"`.Then it should work in javascript